# Too much logic in class

Tags: vue.js, methods, nuxt.js

So i have made this code, and it works as it should

```
<tr
          v-for="(day, index) in days"
          :key="index"
          :class="[
            { no_target: day.date.format('dddd') == 'Sunday' || day.date.format('dddd') == 'Saturday' },
            { active: moment == day.date.format('Do dddd') },
          ]"
          class="calendar-row"
        >
```

This is adds the class of no_target to weekend days and active to todays date.
However my boss thinks this is too much logic inside of a class and would like me to move it to method or computed property.
I cannot really seem to think of a solution for this.

any of you sharp minds here got a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a method like this could help

```
methods: {
    isHoliday(day) {
      const formattedDay = day.date.format("dddd");
      return ["Sunday", "Saturday"].includes(formattedDay);
    },
  },
```

so you can do this

```
<tr v-for="(day, index) in days"
          :key="index"
          :class="[
            { no_target: isHoliday(day)},
            { active: moment == day.date.format('Do dddd') },
          ]"
          class="calendar-row">
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<tr
          v-for="(day, index) in days"
          :key="index"
          :class="[
            { no_target: isHoliday },
            { active: isActive },
          ]"
          class="calendar-row"
        >
```

and in you'r script:

```
data() {
    return {
        isHoliday: false,
        isActive: false
    }
},
mounted: {
    IsHoliday()
    IsActive()
},
methods: {
    IsHoliday() {
     if (day.date.format('dddd') == 'Sunday' || day.date.format('dddd') == 'Saturday') {
         return true;
     } else {
            return false;
       }
    },
    IsActive() {
        if(moment == day.date.format('Do dddd')) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```